# if statement doesn't seem to work

Tags: ios, if-statement, uinavigationcontroller, tableview

I have a little problem with my if statement when `date.name` is about this app News item : 
Does somebody can help me?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MoreMenu *data = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([data.name compare:@"about this app"]) {
        NSLog(@"About this app : %@", data.name);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"News item : %@", data.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: We can't help you with a problem if you won't tell us what it is. If you getting an error, then what kind? If you are getting unexpected results, then what do you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to the pattern of the C standard function `strcmp()`, `-compare:` returns 0 in case of equality. Try

```
if ([data.name isEqualToString:@"about this app"]) {
    // code
}
```

or

```
if (![data.name compare:@"about this app"]) {
    // code
}
```

instead (the first notation is preferred).

Comment: +1 Better answer (although I think it's better to do `== NSOrderedSame` in the second case)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
if ([data.name isEqualToString:@"about this app"])
```

Comment: I know :), but it says i have to wait 7 min :(

Comment: @DannyBoevéé - I think H2CO3 gave a better answer. consider accepting it (when you can)

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking for equality, you probably want to use:

`isEqualToString:` instead of `compare:`